# DJANGO 3.1 'crispy_forms_tags' is not a registered tag library

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm stuck on this and its driving me crazy. I installed django-crispy-forms and added it in the settings.INSTALLED_APPS. Also, I had installed the django-crispy-forms in my virtual environment then freeze on my requirements.txt. Any help would be great.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.Contrib. staticfiles',
'crispy_forms',
'leads',
'tailwind',
'them',
'bootstrap4',
```

client_form.py

```
    {% extends "crm/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <h3>
        {% if client %}
            <b>Client: </b> {{ client.name }}
        {% else %}
            <b>New Client</b>
        {% endif %}
    </h3>

    <form method="POST" class="uniForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-control">
            {{form.name|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            {{form.address|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            {{form.remarks|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" type="submit">Update</button>

    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Have you tried just to load `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}` without form tag?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your `settings.py`

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```